# Charset to save binary data

Tags: java, string, 8-bit

Is there charset which I could use to save 8bit data? I mean everything which is binary, without changing it content in string?

Comment: Are you looking for [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding?

Comment: What makes string class that can't hold binary data? Why is that so?

Answer (score 4):

The package java.io defines two kinds of classes to save data:

- XXXOutputStream, which are for saving raw 8-bytes data
- XXXWriter, which are for saving Strings

Just use the class from XXXOutputStream family that suits your needs. You don't need a Charset for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the datatype `byte[]`.

Comment: but ain't there possibility to use String as byte[] ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. You want to use a `String` to manage binary data? Is that it?